# Fetching data from websocket to react

Tags: reactjs, websocket, communication

I'm relatively new to React, and am looking to combine my React application with a websocket connection.

I'm able to establish a connection via the websocket connection, but am unable to display in my app.

backend code is

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import random
import datetime
import websockets
import json

async def handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        data = [
           
            { 
              "name": "Random Int 1",
              "number": random.randint(0, 3000),
              "category": "Pun" 
            }
        ]
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "127.0.0.1", 8888)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

the react code is

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
const [number, setNumber] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
   const ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8888/");

   ws.onopen = () => {
   console.log("Connection Established!");};
   ws.onmessage = (event) => {
   const data  = JSON.parse(event.data);
   console.log(data);

   setNumber({data.number});};
   ws.onclose = () => {
   console.log("Connection Closed!");};

   ws.onerror = () => {
   console.log("WS Error");};
   return () => {
   ws.close();
 };
}, []);

return (<div>
   <p>number :{person.number}</p>
   </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of minor errors in your code:

Update your `setNumber()` to:

```js
setNumber(data.number);
```

and `person.number` doesn't exist (as the variable is just `number`, so:

```html
<p>number: {number}</p>
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, still not able to see the value on the browser, what else i can try

Comment: it say undefined